# How do I color widgets in LambdaTerm?

Tags: ocaml

I was playing around with the examples [`buttons.ml`](https://github.com/ocaml-community/lambda-term/blob/master/examples/buttons.ml), [`checkbuttons.ml`](https://github.com/ocaml-community/lambda-term/blob/master/examples/checkbuttons.ml), and [`radiobuttons.ml`](https://github.com/ocaml-community/lambda-term/blob/master/examples/radiobuttons.ml) in the [lambda-term](https://github.com/ocaml-community/lambda-term/) library, and I noticed that all of the "dynamic" examples (i.e. involving events, resizing the terminal, etc.) were in black and white, while all of the color examples were "static" (i.e. no events).

Is there any way to have colored widgets, that is, to associate a widget with a color?

For example, is there any way to color the buttons of `buttons.ml` different colors without hardcoding based on location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but not with the base widget provided in lambda-term.

It's not particularly complicated, it's simply historical. I suggest you either:

- Patch the lambda-term widget to have color properties
- Copy the code of the widget you want, and tweak them internally, for instance to add colors.